# Trying search by parent div then get rid of data exept anchor tag then trying to get anchortag href

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

hi i am trying search by parent div then get rid of data exept anchor tag then trying to get img src

```
    for images_url_parent in sub_doc.find_all(class_ = ['woocommerce-product-gallery__image flex-active-slide','woocommerce-product-gallery__image']):
        images_url_parent.decompose()
        for images_url_div in images_url_parent:
            images_url = images_url_parent.find_all('a')
            print(images_url)
```

i am trying to just get the anchor tag href

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there sample input HTML and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

As Andrej suggested in the comment, it's better if you post the expected output; however try the following and let me know if it works:

```
for parent_div in sub_doc.find_all(class_=['woocommerce-product-gallery__image flex-active-slide', 'woocommerce-product-gallery__image']):
    anchor_tags = parent_div.find_all('a')
    for anchor_tag in anchor_tags:
        href_value = anchor_tag.get('href')
        if href_value:
            print(href_value)
```